# Laravel Namespaced Routes Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I have a routes file like this:

```
<?php

Route::group(['prefix' => 'project1', 'namespace' => '\App\Project1\Controllers'], function()
{

    Route::get('/', 'UsersController@index');
});
```

But when I try to access `dev.api/project1/`, it will throw an error of:

```
Class App\Http\Controllers\App\Project1\Controllers\UsersController does not exist
```

You may point out that it's obvious, you should do something like:

```
Route::get('/', '\App\Project1\Controllers\UsersController@index');
```

But isn't it useless to declare the namespace without being to actually use it in the first place?

Anyways, what should I do to be able to to call the controllers without prepending the namespace every single time? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, the routes in `app/Http/routes.php` are automatically loaded inside the `App\Http\Controllers` namespace. Inside this file, any namespace you specify will be relative to that parent namespace.

If you would like to modify this behavior, this can be done in the `app/Providers/RouteServiceProvider.php` file.

A couple quick options:

- You could modify the default parent namespace by modifying the `protected $namespace` attribute.
- You could get rid of any default parent namespace by removing the initial `$router->group()` inside the `map()` method.
- You could create a brand new `app/Project1/routes.php` file, and load it inside a second router group, with your `App\Project1\Controllers` as the default parent namespace for any route listed in that file:

  ```
  public function map(Router $router)
  {
      $router->group(['namespace' => $this->namespace], function ($router)     {
          require app_path('Http/routes.php');
      });
      $router->group(['namespace' => 'App\Project1\Controllers'], function ($router)     {
          require app_path('Project1/routes.php');
      });
  }
  ```

Comment: If I go with the 3rd option you provided, how should I structure my routes.php file? Do I need to do something in the original app/Http/routes.php file? Because I want the prefix to be tied with the namespace

Comment: @ChibangDayanan You don't need to do anything to your original routes file. As far as the prefix goes, you can add it to the group in the service provider, or you can not add a group in the service provider at all and just handle it all in your new routes file.